# I want to get the same result as the minst.pkl.gz file. (ex. (n, 32, 32, 3) (n, 1))

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pickle, conv-neural-network

I try to run cnn in my image data like an mnist.pkl.gz file.
I resized the image to 32x32, and made it a pkl file.

resize code

```
img_size = (32, 32)
def resize_img(img_path):
img_lists = os.listdir(img_path)
img_lists = natsort.natsorted(img_lists)
for img_name in img_lists:
    print(f'{img_path}{img_name}')
    image = Image.open(f'{img_path}{img_name}')
    image = image.resize(img_size)
    image.save(f'{img_path}{img_name}')
resize_img('train/')
```

pickling code (source: https://github.com/tikroute/mnist.pkl.gz-dataset-creator)

```
print("Gonna process:\n\t %s"%glob_files)
dataset = []
for file_count, file_name in enumerate( sorted(glob(glob_files),key=len) ):
    #image = Image.open(file_name)
    img = Image.open(file_name) #.convert('LA') #tograyscale
    pixels = [f[0] for f in list(img.getdata())]
    dataset.append(pixels)
    if file_count % 1000 == 0:
        print("\t %s files processed"%file_count)
# outfile = glob_files+"out"
# np.save(outfile, dataset)
if len(loc_train_labels) > 0:
    df = pd.read_csv(loc_train_labels, names = ["class"])
    return np.array(dataset), np.array(df["class"])
else:
    return np.array(dataset)
```

I loaded the pkl file and checked the shape of the train_set.
The result is : train_images - `(2758, 1024)` train_labels - `(2758, )`

Then I executed the following code.

```
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 32, 32, 3)
```

But an error occurred.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-8-a380a618ad52> in <module>
----> 1 train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 32, 32, 3)
      2 valid_images = valid_images.reshape(valid_images.shape[0], 32, 32, 3)
      3 test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], 32, 32, 3)
      4 
      5 train_images = train_images.astype('float32')

  ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2824192 into shape (2758,32,32,3)
```

I want to get results like train_images - `(2758, 32, 32, 3)` labels - `(2758, 1)`.

Is there a way to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

The dataset you are using does not have 3 RGB channels. But it is greyscaled data with only 1 channel.

If you calculate:

```
2758 * 32 * 32 = 2824192
```

Therefore try this instead.

```
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 32, 32, 1)
```

If each of the image in your dataset has a shape of 32 * 32 * 3 then

Just change the `img_size = (32, 32)` to `img_size = (32, 32, 3)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to use the RGB image!